# Using Graph API with password grant type for a federated ID with Powershell

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, federated-identity

I am trying to create a batch which changes users' MFA phone number in case it got screwed up and an unreachable phone number has been set.

The API does not support application permissions, so I am thinking of using password grant type and implementing the encrypted ID and password of the Administrator. I know this is far from optimal, but I just don't see any other way.

Here is the code I use.

```
$ReqTokenBody = @{
  Grant_Type    = "Password"
  Client_Id     = $clientID
  Client_Secret = $clientSecret
  Username      = $privilegedAuthenticationManager
  Password      = $password
  Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}

$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
```

The problem that I am facing, is that this is only supported with managed IDs (not synced from ADs), and I would really like to use federated IDs as that is company policy.

Is there a way to do this in powershell? If not, in C# maybe?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use the MSAL or ADAL library it will handle the federation authentication for you (eg does WSTrust SOAP post against your ADFS server's active endpoint).  There are modules for both MSAL and ADAL in the powershell gallery eg https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/4.2.1.3

The code to use it is directly yourself is pretty simple though for ADAL

```
Import-Module .\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll -Force
$ClientId = "5471030d-f311-4c5d-91ef-74ca885463a7"

$Credentials = get-credential
$domain = $Credentials.UserName.ToString().Split('@')[1]

$TenantId = (Invoke-WebRequest https://login.windows.net/$domain/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration | ConvertFrom-Json).token_endpoint.Split('/')[3]

$ClientCredentials = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserPasswordCredential" -ArgumentList $Credentials.UserName.ToString(),$Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString()
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId")
return ([Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($Context,"https://graph.microsoft.com", $ClientId ,$ClientCredentials)).Result
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it out, and I cannot seem to get an access token. Maybe I am just not doing it right. When I do `$result = ([Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($Context,"https://graph.microsoft.com", $ClientId ,$ClientCredentials)).Result` the result is null. I am not getting any error messages. Also, this code does not seem to use ClientSecrets. Is this an expected thing? Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: If you want to use the ROPC grant then your app must be a public client so no secret is required https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc. I'd suggest you run fiddler on the machine where you testing it this will allow you to see what is happening behind the scenes (eg the discover and federation requests etc). If its failing in the federation side it can get complicated eg some people lock down active endpoints in federation, requests can also be treated differently if they are going through a proxy etc.

Comment: I am currently testing with a managed ID (admin@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com) so there should be no errors regarding federation. Is there some sort of setting that I have to do in Azure portal to make my app public?

Comment: Yes on the Authentication page of the Application Registration- Under Advanced settings \ Default Client Type (the default isn't to be a public client). I would still use fiddler to look at the requests its sometime the only way to debug these issues.

Comment: The public app settings worked and I got the token. I've also tried the entire script with a managed ID and it seems to be working. Let me try this with a federated ID in production environment tomorrow. Thanks a lot for the guidance!

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up, this worked in production as well. I have accepted your answer. Thank you again for your kind help.